# Using coordinatorLayout anchor's with constraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-constraintlayout

I want to design something like this :

[image]

as you can see fab is between header and the body.

it's easy to do it with **coordinatorLayout** with `app:anchor` and `app:anchorGravity` attributes

but i want to do it with **constraintLayout**.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the answer :))

```
<FAB
   ...
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/body"/>
```

Comment: By this, you're only positioning the FAB, but if you want to make use of material design animations you should use CoordinatorLayout as your parent, e.g. for the parallax.

Comment: Yes you are right, but i just needed to position the fab between those two layouts.

Comment: Could you post the role code? I'm with a problem with this... My "header" keeping in front of fab button

Comment: @FelipeA. You need to move your FAB xml tag below other tags (header and body)